# Can Cognito Groups be used to manage Row/Column level access in Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, user-permissions, amazon-athena

[AWS Cognito Groups](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/) offer a pretty powerful means of making user groups and permissions. I need to manage user data access at a row/column level in Athena, Aurora, etc.

1. Is there a way to use Cognito to manage user data access?
2. Can we manage parameter access to ApiGateway? For example, restrict users from hitting `/data/{company_name}` for company names they don't have permissions to.

Please provide links to documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, I have not seen Athena being controlled with Row or Column Level access with IAM or any other policy.

If you want to restrict certain paths in url in API-Gateway you can use custom authorizer.

**Custom Authorizer with Example:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html

Hope it helps.